# Заменить группу в регулярном выражении python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужно заменить в строке совпадение с группой в регулярном выражении.
Пусть есть `foo42buz`, нужно получить `foobarbuz`
Очевидно, я сразу пытаюсь написать что-то такое

```
string = 'foo42buz'
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)buz')
re.sub(pattern,'bar',string)
```

Но это возвращает ту же `foo42buz`

Гуглю как заменить совпадение именно с группой и пытаюсь делать так

```
string = 'foo42buz'
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)buz')
re.sub(pattern,r'\1bar',string)
```

и так

```
string = 'foo42buz'
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)buz')
re.sub(pattern,r'\g<1>bar',string)
```

и даже так

```
string = 'foo42buz'
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<name>\d+)buz')
re.sub(pattern,r'\g<name>bar',string)
```

Но re.sub ведет себя очень неочевидным для меня образом, возвращая `foo42buz`

---

Попробую еще раз. Есть строка, есть регулярка с группой. Необходимо в строке подстроку совпадающую с группой заменить на другую подстроку. 
Есть строка `foo42buz`, есть регулярка  `(\d+)buz`, где группа `(\d+)` совпадает с подстрокой `42`. Нужно заменить это совпадение другой строкой `bar`, чтобы получилась в итоге строка `foobarbuz`.

Comment: Кстати, Ваш код (первый фрагмент) таки возвращает `foobar`. Видимо, Вы имели в виду `string = re.sub(pattern,'bar',string)`

Comment: Таки да, там фубар. Но все еще не то поведение, которое мне нужно. И самое главное - не могу понять, почему именно так.

Comment: Дал еще один (верный) ответ))

Comment: Хотите сказать, что регулярное выражение и номер группы задаётся пользователем, и надо заменить значение указанной группы? Тогда ни  один из ответов неверен.

Comment: Может, [так](http://ideone.com/ocu1sM)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще 1 вариант, но это экзотика :)

```
>>> re.sub(re.findall(r'(\d+)buz', string)[0], 'bar', string)
'foobarbuz'
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваша проблема вероятно, что вы думаете, что `pattern.sub(repl, text)` изменяет `text`. Строки в Питоне неизменяемы. Чтобы текст поменялся (новое значение получить):

```
text = pattern.sub(repl, text)
```

---

Чтобы только цифры заменить, можно lookahead assertion использовать:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\d+(?=buz)', 'bar', 'foo42buz')
'foobarbuz'
```

Comment: Опередили. Добавлю, если нужно заменять только цифры, стоящие между `foo` и `bar` - используйте `positive lookbehind` - `re.sub(r'(?<=foo)\d+(?=bar)', 'buz', 'foo42bar')`

Comment: Я знаю о неизменяемости строк и веду речь именно о возвращаемом значении. Возвращается же то, что и было, а не новая строка с замененной группой.

Вопрос не в замене цифер, а именно в замене совпадений с группой. Пример с цифрами - просто пример.

Comment: @NikBond  Код в ответе работает как показано. Что вы хотите, чтобы он вернул? Приведите входную строку ('foo42buz') и что вы хотите получить ('foobarbuz')

Comment: @jfs Попробую еще раз. Есть строка, есть регулярка с группой. Необходимо в строке подстроку совпадающую с группой заменить на другую подстроку. 
Есть строка 'foo42buz', есть регулярка  '(\d+)buz', где группа (\d+) совпадает с подстрокой '42'. Нужно заменить это совпадение другой строкой 'bar', чтобы получилась в итоге строка 'foobarbuz'.
Приведенный вами код возвращает foobar https://ideone.com/2UYOjj

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @NikBond, в предложенном ответе `(?=buz)` скобочки и вопросики - вовсе не для красоты. Попробуйте скопипастить еще раз.

Comment: @NikBond: вы неправильный pattern используете. В ответе явно указано [`r'\d+(?=buz)'`, что возвращает `'foobarbuz'`
`](http://ideone.com/SnnEvt)

Answer (score 3):

Правильные ответы даны. Еще один вариант (с использованием синтаксиса `\N`)

```
>>> re.sub(r'(foo)\d+(bar)', r'\1buz\2', '--foo42bar--')
'--foobuzbar--'
>>>
```

В группы Вам нужно выделять как раз то, что должно остаться в строке, чтобы использовать в "строке замены". `re.sub`, условно говоря, меняет на второй аргумент, целиком объект `match`, или `match.group(0)`. Любую группу (в том числе `\0` можно использовать во втором аргументе.
Грубо говоря, `result = re.sub(pattern, rep, string)` эквивалентно

```
m = pattern.search(string)
if m:
   result = string.replace(m.group(0), rep)
```

С той разницей, что в `rep` можно использовать специальные символы `\N` для подстановки `m.group(N)`.

То есть прямо так, как Вы хотите

> Необходимо в строке подстроку совпадающую с группой заменить на другую подстроку.

сделать нельзя.

Comment: Как вы [сами уже писали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656336/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-python/656346#comment942294_656346), lookahead и lookbehind здесь работают — группы не нужны в этом примере.

Comment: Да я не спорю, сам точно такой же ответ хотел дать. Зато с группами можно так `>>> re.sub(r'(foo)\d+(bar)', r'\2buz\1', '--foo42bar--') --> '--barbuzfoo--'`